# Updating Body with AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Trying to build a small website that has the same header and footer, but updates the body section. Currently, I have the header, body, and footer pages displayed in my index.html, but not sure how to update the body section when clicking the button load page_02.

This is the code I have so far:

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>AngularJS Page Management</title>
    <script src="../../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="pageManager">
       <div ng-include="header = 'header.html'"></div>
       <div ng-include="body = 'page1.html'"></div>
       <div ng-include="footer = 'footer.html'"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

header.html

```
<div class="mainHeader">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <form action="page2.html">
        <input type="submit" value="Load Page_02">
    </form>
</div>
```

page1.html

```
<div class="page1">
    <h1>Body - Page_01</h1>  
</div>
```

page2.html

```
<div class="page2">
    <h1>Body - Page_02</h1>
</div>
```

footer.html

```
<div class="mainFooter">
    <h1>Footer</h1>
</div>
```

controller.js

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('pageManager', function($scope) {
        $scope.header = "header.html";
        $scope.body = "page1.html";
        $scope.footer = "footer.html";
    });
```

styles.css

```
* {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.mainHeader {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}

.mainFooter {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}

.page1 {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}

.page2 {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: You can achieve that with Angular routing. One great example with demo included can be found here https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating Good luck!

Comment: You should take a look at [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for angular, I think it is more appropriate. If you do not want to use ui-router you can use the property ng-show="" to render a specific template. In other words you keep a boolean value to say if you render the page or not. Another way to do it is to create a filter and render the page with the filter on ng-show.

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys. I am pretty new to Angular so wasn't sure of a good approach. I think the ui-router looks like a great option! I'll go research it!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ngRoute` or `ui.router` please see demo here using ngRoute http://plnkr.co/edit/sFcpDrGMy3CmsKJgTZH1?p=preview

```
<body ng-app="newappt">
  <div class="mainHeader">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <a href="#/page1">Page 1</a> | <a href="#/page2">Page 2</a>
  </div>
  <div ng-view="" class="container"></div>
  <div class="mainFooter">
    <h1>Footer</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

and js:

```
var newappt = angular.module('newappt', ['ngRoute']);


newappt.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/page1', {
      templateUrl: 'page1.html',
      controller: 'pageManager'


    })
    .when('/page2', {
      templateUrl: 'page2.html',
      controller: 'pageManager'
      })

  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/page1'
  });
});

newappt.controller('pageManager', function($scope) {


});
```